# Looking for an existing proof for a property of triangles

Tags: reference-request, inequality, triangles

In my paper, I need the following lemma. I can prove it, but it is a little lengthy to be put inside the paper. I am wondering is there any existing proof that I can quote.

> **Lemma 1**: Let the nodes of a triangle $K$ be $A$, $B$ and $C$, and the longest edge length
> of $K$ be $h$ (see attached figure).
> Then, the following inequality holds
> $$\min_{P \in K}\max(|PA|, |PB|, |PC|) \le \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} h\:.$$
> Moreover, the equality holds only for a regular triangle with $P$ being the circumcenter of $K$.

[image: Triangle]

The 3D version of the above Lemma is as follows.

> **Lemma 2** For any tetrahedron $K$, the vertices of which are denoted by $A,B,C,D$, let $h$ be the longest edge length.
> Then,
> $$\min_{P \in K} \max (|PA|, |PB|,|PC|, |PD|) \le \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} h $$
> Moreover, the equality holds only for a regular tetrahedron $K$ with $P$ selected as the circumcenter of $K$;

Comment: Are you looking for references on both cases?

Comment: A reference for either lemma is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: fermat-torricelli point?

Comment: It is not the Fermat-Torricelli point. In fact, for an acute triangle, the P is just the circumcenter of K. For an obtuse triangle, P is the midpoint of the longest edge.

Comment: Partial proof is found in a paper: http://goo.gl/Ru82z1 
This paper shows that for a fixed triangle, the P that minimizes max(PA, PB, PC) is the circumcenter of K or the mid-point of two nodes.

Comment: Thanks to comment from Prof. S. Akiyama, I got 
 to know this theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung's_theorem

Answer (score 1):

This is well discussed in the Jung's theorem: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung's_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung%27s_theorem)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.